# VBA networkdays not updating formulea

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which **calculates the number of days between two days**. In a separate worksheet the **user can input the days to exclude from the calculation.**

However the macro is **not updating calculation** based on the users request to exclude certain days. Please see my code below.

> Sub Numberof_Days()
>
> Dim LastRow As Long
>
> ```
> LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
> Range("S11").Select
> Do Until ActiveCell.row = LastRow + 1
>     If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
> ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
>     "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-14],RC[-12],'Non-Valuation Days'!R[-7]C[-18]:R[57]C[-18])"
>     End If
>     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
> Loop End Sub
> ```

Comment: If you just paste "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-14],RC[-12],'Non-Valuation Days'!R[-7]C[-18]:R[57]C[-18])" into the worksheet what does it return?

Comment: what does the real formula look like?

Comment: @314unreadEmails it returns the difference between the days . But when the user enters a date not to b include I have to update the calculation manully

Comment: @Davesexcel the formulea is =NETWORKDAYS(E11,G11,'Non-Valuation Days'!A4:A49)

Comment: Between A4-A49 in Non valuation days worksheet the user can input the days not to be included.

Comment: @pnuts even if the code is reran , i have to go where there is red flag error to update it.

Comment: one cell will update however the rest need to be update manually. i though    the loop would have done the trick

Comment: I think it should be` "=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-14],RC[-12],'Non-Valuation Days'!R4C1:R49C1)"` which works out to be,`=NETWORKDAYS(E11,G11,'Non-Valuation Days'!$A$4:$A$49)`

Comment: @Davesexcel thanks for that. you correct. School boy error on my part .

Comment: You should name the range `'Non-Valuation Days'!$A$4:$A$49` or probably a whole column for these Non-Valuation days, it makes maintenance much easier. And use this name in the NetWorkDays formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be`"=NETWORKDAYS(RC[-14],RC[-12],'Non-Valuation Days'!R4C1:R49C1)"`